# Developing FIrebug like web application for CSS things

Tags: javascript, css, firebug, firebug-lite

I am developing a web application for web designing. One part of it includes changing CSS styles on the run and saving the same back to server.
I see that, first part of my motive is implemented there in firebug, where I can view CSS style rules applied to a particular HTML element and can change them to view the effect.
An earlier question at SO lead to me firebug lite source code https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js , which is far less confusing than full version of firebug.
My question was that, is there any way I can get documentation of the firebug/firebug lite code which can speed things up for me.
After some googling I found out that there is Firebug API

http://getfirebug.com/developer/api/firebug1.6/

But don't know how much useful it is for me.

Any alternative way to do this is also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Firebug uses a BSD-style license, which pretty much means you can use their code in your application without too many restrictions:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#Proprietary_software_licenses_compatibility

I would suggest you contact the developers of Firebug directly.  I'm sure they would be interested in providing assistance with what you are trying to accomplish.

In my opinion, the ability to sync changes to a file or server is the one thing that's missing from this powerful tool, and I'm interested to see what the final result looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do went through licensing things before trying to use their code. Though thanks for confirmation. And Its a long way to go to complete, what I am trying to do. But excited too for the development...

Comment: @Vishwanath - What are you planning on doing with the final result?  I'd be interested to try it out.  I hope you'll release it!  My suggestion, get something out as soon as you can so you can start getting user feedback.  Let me know how it progresses.  You can contact me on my blog:  http://blog.opensourceopportunities.com.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Backfire](http://blog.quplo.com/2010/08/backfire-save-css-changes-made-in-firebug/) project, which "allows you to save CSS changes made with Firebug, Webkit Developer Toolbar or any other clientside debugging tool." The project page says that it was developed to be able to support various backends. The [Backfire source code is available](http://code.google.com/p/backfire/) under an MIT license.

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a possible answer to my own question.

Found following which gives a small amount of information about Firebug internals.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firebug_internals